# How can I hold back some packages when upgrading releases?

Tags: upgrade, package-management

There are a number of questions that address holding back packages with apt or dpkg to prevent upgrades when doing a normal 'apt-get upgrade'. Will any of these methods work across a release upgrade? I'm finally upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04, and there are some packages (e.g., MySQL server) that I'd like to prevent from being upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming such constraints were enforces by the upgrade manager, there's a good chance that you'll have broken dependencies and will have to hold back other packages to avoid the broken dependencies. If any of those other packages are critical/core packages, the upgrade manager will refuse to continue.

In the case of MySQL, this *might* be less likely based on the dependencies and reverse-dependencies of the `mysql-server-5.5` package in Trusty.